# Using tree with tar.gz file without extracting contents

Tags: linux, tar, tree

I am wondering if it's possible to output the contents of a tar.gz file using tree without having to extract the contents of the file to a temp directory then using tree with that directory.

I know we can see the contents of the file without extracting using

```
tar -tf file.tar.gz
```

And I have simply tried piping this to the `tree` command

```
tar -tf file.tar.gz | tree
```

But this just outputs the tree of the current directory, not the contents of the file.

A few questions,

1. Is this even possible?
2. If it is possible, are there any limitations? Depth, number of files, etc?
3. Is there an alternative way to see a tree style output of the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom tree script [treeify.py](https://bitbucket.org/Hakril/treeify/src) created by Hakril would help to pretty print contents of tgz without extracting

```
[root@bastion ~]# wget https://bitbucket.org/Hakril/treeify/raw/8e732368f64d30ffc4033cbc890164fdf296d9f8/treeify.py
[root@bastion ~]# tar -tvf  neo4j-enterprise.tar.gz | python treeify.py 
.
├─ drwxrwxrwx root
│  ├─ root         0 2019-05-09 05:05 neo4j-enterprise
│  │  └─ local-package
│  │    └─ 
│  └─ root         0 2019-05-15 02:01 neo4j-enterprise
│    └─ 
└─ -rwxr-xr-x root
  ├─ root         0 2019-05-09 05:05 neo4j-enterprise
  │  ├─ local-package
  │  │  └─ .sentinel
  │  └─ .sentinel
  ├─ root     10156 2019-05-09 05:05 neo4j-enterprise
  │  └─ docker-entrypoint.sh
  └─ root      1560 2019-05-14 21:36 neo4j-enterprise
    └─ Dockerfile
[root@bastion ~]#
```

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/1086501/list-contents-of-tarball-in-tree-format

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am getting an error per the python code:

Comment: [05-21-2019__11:12:29] root@MININT-L62JL0A:/usr/local# ls | python treeify.py
  File "treeify.py", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Error output says 'DOCTYPE html'.  Can you double check the python script?.

Comment: Yeah, so the py file I downloaded from bitbucket for that developer is all HTML, there is no python code anywhere. Any ideas? Are you seeing the same thing if you download it?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I'm an idiot ha. I copied the link to the file directly from bitbucket and used wget on that but it looks like I have to download the whole repo instead.

Comment: You can only download the python script. I just updated the answer.

Comment: I appreciate it Naveen, I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: Sweet, Yay!! my first answer in this site.

Comment: You should definitely consider using `tar -tf` flag instead of `-tvf` for a better result. `-v` flag means verbose which ruins the tree view. See `tar --help`.